# Inserting element into sequence while mapping over it in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a vector of the form *[ ["H"] ["B"] ["ER"] ["W"] ]* and I want a vector of the form *[ ["H"] ["B"] ["E"] ["R"] ["W"] ]* with the E and the R naturally separated.

I'm quite familiar with map (and reduce) and have been using them a lot but for some reason I can't think of a way to do this easily using map.

Can map produce two elements or more for each input it receives from a sequence? If so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`mapcat`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/mapcat) is what you’re looking for.

With `mapcat` you return a *collection* for each input element. The collections are concatenated into the result. For example:

```
(vec
  (mapcat #(map (comp vector str) (first %))
          [["H"] ["B"] ["ER"] ["W"]]))
```

Comment: Thanks!! I knew there must have been an elegant solution I was missing.